# How do I collect unwanted values?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using COUNT(*) to count the number of items with different values in a column.

I've used this query:

```sql
SELECT `type`, COUNT(*) FROM `fruits` GROUP BY `type`
```

`status` is a column where the values are either 'Apples', 'Oranges', 'Grapes', 'Bananas'

So the result is:

```sql
+------------+---------+
|    Type    | COUNT(*)|
+------------+---------+
| Apples     |       30|
| Oranges    |        8|
| Bananas    |        6|
| Grapes     |        2|
+------------+---------+
```

But I just want 'Apples' and 'Oranges' to be counted. The rest is put into a single row. Like this:

```sql
+------------+---------+
|    Type    | COUNT(*)|
+------------+---------+
| Apples     |       30|
| Oranges    |        8|
| Others     |        8|
+------------+---------+
```

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `case when` expression

```
SELECT case when `type` in ('Apple','Orange') then `type` else 'Others' end as 'Type', COUNT(*)
FROM `fruits` 
GROUP BY case when `type` in ('Apple','Orange') then `type` else 'Others' end
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Thanks so much! Now I just need to figure out how to rename the column  :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a `case` *expression* in a *derived table* to group others together. Then aggregate its result:

```
select `type`, COUNT(*)
from
(
    SELECT case when `type` in ('Apples','Oranges') then `type`
                else 'Others'
           end as 'type'
    FROM `fruits`
) dt
GROUP BY `type`
```

This way you'll only have to write the case expression once, i.e. less error prone and eaisier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

use case when

```
       SELECT case when type not in('Apples','Oranges')
       then 'others'
       else type end as frt, 
       COUNT(*) FROM `fruits` 
       GROUP BY  case when type not in('Apples','Oranges') then 'others'
       else type end
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `case` statement to get your result. And give alias name to your column as needed.

```
SELECT case when `type` in ('Apple','Orange') then `type` else 'Others' end as 'Type', COUNT(*) as 'COUNT(*)'
FROM `fruits` 
GROUP BY case when `type` in ('Apple','Orange') then `type` else 'Others' end
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL allows you to use table aliases in the `GROUP BY`.  So, if you change the name, you can do:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN type IN ('Apples', 'Oranges')
             THEN type
             ELSE 'Others'
        END) as grp,
       COUNT(*)
FROM fruits
GROUP BY grp;
```

This can be a big convenience when working with complex expressions.